# Client Object Model (javascript without master page)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to code using JSOM, I've done this in SPD and added a master page to a blank aspx page (spd). However I don't want to see the ribbon and also want to launch the page in a dialog box. 
Hence decided to try without the master page however the code doesn't work. There are numerous sites explaining adding scriptlink/SOD but can't get this to work.
Here is the code of a blank aspx page created in SPD, Could someone suggest what code needs adding and where please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to execute code that retrieves items from a list as described here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Add Following JS references to your blank page: i.e 
1. MicrosoftAjax.js
2. sp.runtime.js
3. sp.js

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/sp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here is the hyperlink i found while doing some google - http://aviralchawda.blogspot.in/

Comment: Hi Seems to work but another error down the line..
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
Does not work, it requires a relative url. Can I get the current site at runtime?

Comment: I am not sure about that but You can provide site collection URL directly in ClientContext .......Try follwing line and check if it is working --->                                                                                                      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://..........');